# Equivalent matrices represent the same linear map in different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

It is clear from the change of basis formula that the matrices $A$ and $B$ representing the same linear map in different bases are equivalent: there exists invertible matrixes $Q$ and $P$ such that $A=Q^{-1}BP$.

My question is about the other way, I mean given two equivalent matrices $A$ and $B$ in $M_{n,p}(\mathbb K)$ why they must represent the same linear map in different bases ? thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm talking about equivalent matrices not similar matrices. $A$ and $B$ are not square matrix they are of type $(n,p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $B$ being an $m \times n$ matrix represents a transformation $\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ where we take the standard basis in each space.  If $A = Q^{-1}BP$, then take a basis for $\Bbb R^n$ made up of the columns of $P$ and a basis for $\Bbb R^m$ made up of the columns of $Q$.  Then $A$ represents the transformation with respect to these new bases.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix elements $\{\langle i|A|j\rangle,1\le i\le n,1\le j\le p\}$ of $A$ with respect to a given basis sets $\{\langle i|\}$ and $\{|j\rangle\}$, are the same as $\{\langle i|Q^{-1}BP|j\rangle,1\le i\le n,1\le j\le p\}$, which are the matrix elements of $B$ with respect to new basis sets given by $\{P|j\rangle,1\le j\le p\}$ and $\{\langle i|Q^{-1},1\le i\le n\}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I don't see what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the notation and gave some more details

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple generalization of similarity (where you consider only $n\times n$ matrices with the *same* basis in domain and range). Here $P$ is the change-of-basis matrix in the domain ($\Bbb K^p$) and $Q$ is the change-of-basis matrix in the range ($\Bbb K^n$).